# How to use early jdk with archlinux-java?

Tags: java, openjdk

I'm using `archlinux-java set java-xx-openjdk` to switch between regularly installed jdk versions, and that works, but I want to use the latest or the early version from https://jdk.java.net/ that I have installed manually in /opt (for example)

I'm unable to switch to `/opt/jdk-19` java version, I also tried to create a symlink in `/usr/lib/jvm/` beside the other versions, but it's not detected.

- how does `archlinux-java status` work? Could I register custom jdk?
- how could I package it if I want to create a regular installation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Java's path to your `.bashrc` (assuming that you're using `bash`).

Personally, I like to use [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io/), since there you can pick-and-choose which Java provider to install and which version, in addition to it being *really* easy to set up.

Comment: Yes it works, I just tried it and the early version is available. It doesn't use archlinux-java though, still usefull for other tools installs.

Comment: @pdem I see you made it work. I upvoted your post for visibility.

Answer (score 1):

My bad: archlinux-java doesn't work with symlinks, I have to copy it in:
`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-19`
then archlinux-java status detect it.

Here is the full install after download (the tar contains the jdk-19 folder):

```
$ sudo tar xvf ~/Downloads/openjdk-19_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz --directory /usr/lib/jvm/
$ archlinux-java status
java-11-openjdk (default)
java-17-adoptopenjdk
java-8-adoptopenjdk
java-8-openjdk/jre
jdk-19

$ sudo archlinux-java set jdk-19
```

so basically, `archlinux-java status` makes a `ll /usr/lib/jvm`